# django-alexa unable to read intents

Tags: python, django, alexa-skills-kit

As per the Tutorial given by [django-alexa](https://github.com/pycontribs/django-alexa)

When i place alexa.py in my project folder

```
myalexa/
db.sqlite3
manage.py
insurance/
    admin.py
    alexa.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
    __init__.py
    migrations/
        __init__.py
myalexa/
    .gitignore
    LICENSE
    README.md
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
    __init__.py
```

and i did

> \myalexa>python manage.py alexa_intents

```
{
"intents": [
    {
        "intent": "LaunchRequest",
        "slots": []
    },
    {
        "intent": "CancelIntent",
        "slots": []
    },
    {
        "intent": "StopIntent",
        "slots": []
    },
    {
        "intent": "HelpIntent",
        "slots": []
    },
    {
        "intent": "SessionEndedRequest",
        "slots": []
    }
]
```

}

as per the tutorial it should give my intents that are present in my alexa.py
but is still give me the old content what am i doing wrong.

and also how do i find my
ALEXA_APP_ID_my_app=as per the tutorial amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.e18a3326-4775-45f2-83n0-5eeg03832401
but what i get is "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.6aad0e83-2b02-4c83-9063-58374b780c7d"

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure `django-alexa` is the right choice of library - it hasn't had any new commits in some time. Personally, I found [Flask-ask](https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask) worked quite well when I used it recently. In the end I used [echokit](https://github.com/arcward/echokit) which has less functionality but was easier to deploy to AWS lambda.

Comment: Correct i am using flask-ask as of now. But my entire project is in django  and i want to integrate alexa in it. flask-ask is just an alternative for me any help on django-alexa will help me